# DNS Flusher for Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Is there an extension for Google Chrome to do same thing that Firefox DNS Flusher does?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just a two-clicks operation, add **chrome://net-internals/#dns** as a bookmark on the bookmark bar. Click it to open config page and click "Clear host cache" button.

related: [How to clear/flush the DNS cache in Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

try [DNS Flusher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fegcjmebpcoihkfdjilmnemfkgjbneol) for Chrome

Note that to use it, it requires command line flag `--enable-benchmarking` when you start the chrome browser.