# Chrome Residual Redirect to Login Page

Tags: wireless-networking, dns, redirection

My college redirects people in the dorms to a login page when using an ethernet (or wifi) connection. I am now at home, and certain domains keep redirecting to this login page. I've tried running ipconfig /flushdns and I flushed the chrome's local dns cache as described here: [How to clear/flush the DNS cache in Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome).

Interestingly enough, while http://www.reddit.com redirects to the login page, http://www.reddit.com/r/funny works. Firefox works fine for both urls.

Is there a way to fix this without deleting all of my cookies?

Thanks!