# How come hosts file redirection fails?

Tags: hosts, hosts-file

I am trying to redirect google.com to my local machine for fun and learning with this /etc/hosts file on my Mac.

```
127.0.0.1 www.google.com
```

However, www.google.com still maps to the Google home page when I visit it in Chrome on my Mac. Why?

Basically, this is all I did:

1. Type `sudo vim /etc/hosts` in terminal.
2. Inputted `127.0.0.1 www.google.com` into the hosts file.
3. Saved and quit vim.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `hosts` file doesn't work this way. You can only use it to map an hostnames to IP addresses, not to `localhost`.

For your case you'd use `127.0.0.1 www.google.com`, i.e. map www.google.com to 127.0.0.1.

If you want to map more hostnames to a singe IP, you just add those hostnames in the same line, e.g. `127.0.0.1 www.a.com www.b.com`.

Comment: Thank you. I just changed the /etc/hosts file on my Mac to `127.0.0.1 www.google.com`. However, google.com still leads to the Google home page. Do I need to refresh anything? Should I restart my computer?

Comment: You shouldn't need to. Try adding `127.0.0.1 google.com` (without the www) after this line and check whether it works.

Comment: `127.0.0.1 google.com` isn't working either. I'm not sure what's going on ... I know that `/etc/hosts` is a soft link to `/private/etc/hosts` on a Mac, but I don't think that helps at all.

Comment: Does `127.0.0.1 www.example.com`, then acessing www.example.com, works?

Comment: No, http://www.example.com still oddly leads to http://www.iana.org/domains/example/ on my Mac with `127.0.0.1 www.example.com` as my /etc/hosts file.

Comment: A technicality: `hosts` maps hostnames to IP addresses, not vice versa.

Comment: @Dennis, that’s what I was going to say, but then again, it really does work both ways when you think about it, because it creates an association between two items.

Answer (score 10):

A web browser isn't the best way to check if your `hosts` syntax is correct. Try executing

```
ping www.google.com
```

and verify that it pings `127.0.0.1`.

The reason why Chrome appears to ignore your `hosts` file is caching:

If Chrome has already queried the IP lately (the definition of lately most likely depends on the [time to live (TTL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live#DNS_records) returned by the DNS server), it will bypass the `hosts` file, since it already *knows* the correct IP. This is done to speed up web browsing.

To make Chrome respect the new entry, do the follwing:

1. Edit `/etc/hosts` as @Renan described.
2. Go to `chrome://chrome/settings/clearBrowserData`.
3. Choose `since the beginning of time`.
4. Check `Empty the cache`, but uncheck everything else.
5. Click `Clear browsing data` and wait for it to finish.
6. Restart Chrome.

Chrome should respect your `hosts` file now.

Comment: I learned this a long time ago with IE6. If I made a change to the HOSTS file while IE was still open, I would have to specifically close it and run it again for it to pick up the changes. This goes for most programs. Some programs however (like versions of Chrome from the past year or two) will actually re-read the HOSTS file periodically, so if you make a change, just wait a minute or two, then refresh (no need to clear the cache). (This re-reading policy is handy sometimes like this, but usually pretty bad in reality since it is wasteful, and particularly bad if the HOSTS file is large.)

Comment: @Synetech: Chrome picks up changes in `hosts` instantly, as long as the entry isn't a hostname that's already cached. I *assume* that it checks `hosts` only if the TTL has past. With *big* web sites, that can take a while.

Comment: I don’t know the specifics about how different versions go about re-reading the HOSTS file, but you can use Filemon/ProcMon to see it in action; `chrome.exe` will occasionally read the entire file.

Comment: There is a less brutal way of flushing chrome's DNS cache http://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome

Comment: @hakunin: Neat. On Chromium 25.0.1364.160 Ubuntu 12.04, this isn't even necessary anymore. I checked in `net-internals/#dns`, and the host cache gets cleared automatically when `/etc/hosts` is altered.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a combination of the above because I am connecting to my office via Fortinet SSL VPN for Ubuntu 16.04.

The first thing I had to do is bring up my terminal console and run the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

I added the following example:

```
searchdomain domain.local
nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Then I saved the file by pressing `CTRL-O` and closed nano by pressing `CTRL-X`.

I then did the following and it worked perfectly:

To make Chrome respect the new entry, do the follwing:

Edit `/etc/hosts` as @Renan described.

1. Go to `chrome://chrome/settings/clearBrowserData`.
2. Choose since the beginning of time.
3. Check Empty the cache, but uncheck everything else.
4. Click Clear browsing data and wait for it to finish.
5. Restart Chrome.

Chrome should respect your hosts file now.