# Mountain lion DNS cache flushing

Tags: macos, dns, osx-mountain-lion

After trying,

sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder

sudo dscacheutil -flushcache

Navigating to chrome's dns cache flush page, clearing

[How to clear/flush the DNS cache in Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome)

Trying the same site in Safari

I still see godaddy's 'My Site' placeholder, while my fiance on the computer next to me sees the site I have hosted on Amazon S3.  I know that restarting will fix this issue, as I've had this same issue on Lion and Mountain Lion before, but I'm wondering if there is some known bug or workaround for these DNS issues.

Edit:  restarting had no effect.  I was using Google's DNS servers, and my fiance was not, so I switched, flushed, and tried again with no success.  The domain in question is daloupe.com

Edit:  After another 10 minutes or so, it works.  Perhaps I just don't understand how DNS propagation works, but my fiance and I are on the same network, with the same DNS server, and I was repeatedly flushing my cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was probably still cached by your router or your ISP. Next time try using dig to debug:

`dig superuser.com`

This should give you the IP of the domain you queried for, but more importantly it gives you the IP address of the server responding to your DNS query (probably your router's IP or an IP owned by your ISP).

The dig command uses your network's DNS host by default, not the authoritative DNS server. To query the authoritative source directly, first get the DNS of the authoritative source with nslookup:

`nslookup superuser.com` (returns ns1.serverfault.com et. al)

Then, try something like:

`dig superuser.com @ns1.serverfault.com`