# Google Chrome reads hosts file changes for too long

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, hosts-file

When I use the system hosts file to override DNS, Google Chrome takes longer than I'd like to pick up the changes, sometimes requiring a minute or longer to notice. Is there any way to make this happen immediately, or at least more quickly than it does right now?

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to chrome://net-internals/#dns and press the "Clear host cache" button.

Here you can find the [documentation of Chrome's net-internals page](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/view-net-internals)

And don't forget to clear your windows cache:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Comment: Both solutions doesn't work for me. :(

Comment: Well it's actually work, but still slow, not instant. Time varies.

Comment: more info: http://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome

Comment: Flush the browser cache first (not talking about the "clear host cache" function. And that is one of the things mentioned as working the quickest on the link posted by @XyZZy

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Chrome picks up previous changes just fine, but doesn't pick up my last addition.