# OpenDNS Redirects Website - Firefox Does not Load Body

Tags: website, domain, opendns

I bought a domain and created a website for it. It seems to work, however, after a fraction of a second, OpenDNS redirects me to the "Website Unavailable" page. How can I fix this. I cannot remove OpenDNS, as it is used for parental control.

In addition, the body of the webpage does not load at all when I use Firefox.

Update: Firefox seemed to fix itself. Weird. However, I still get the OpenDNS error in Chromium, but only in Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on when you setup your domain name to point to your server it could have to to with DNS Propagation. [Why DNS Propagation Takes So Long](http://support.powerdnn.com/KB/a604/dns-propagation-and-why-it-takes-so-long-explained.aspx)

Chromium may still be holding on to an old DNS entry, here are instructions to [flush you chromium DNS cache](https://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome)