# How to identify web site inaccessible issue on OSX?

Tags: macos, networking, mac, google-chrome, safari

I would like to know how I can identify this problem. I have been surfing on Internet today without any problem and not setting changed. I really think this is the cause of HTTP packet from internet to Chrome. So, Someone seems be cracking/replace my session.

Of course, I checked 3rd party personal firewall but not Mac one because I did not touch anything since it's rebuilt.

**My environment:**

- OSX Mavericks
- Chrome(No proxy setting)
- Safari(No proxy setting)
- Wired LAN

All are latest patch applied but not yesterday happened.

**Verification:**

- Ping www.apple.com
- telnet www.apple.com 80
- traceroute www.apple.com
- nslookup www.apple.com
- Ping www.google.com
- telnet www.google.com 443
- traceroute www.google.com
- nslookup www.google.com
- personal Symantec application firewall is reseted as default
- chrome://net-internals/#dns (@T Goi suggested me in comment area)

These works fine which means my network interface, DNS, network, web server is up.

**Problem:**

Check to browse apple.com:

- Chrome failed(This webpage is not available.
- Safari Success.

Check to browse no existed domain(which is middle one):

- Chrome failed(of course, Unable to connect to Internet).
- Safari failed(of course, Safari can't find the server).

[image: Browsing www.apple.co.jp chrome and safari]

Based on that I have a several question in below.

1. What will be a cause?
2. How to identify/check the issue.
3. Could you provide me the log of HTTP request/respond packet using Wireshark to compare in my end? (you are not necessary to pick up the log, I will handle it)
4. When I use major 3rd parties firewall software such Symantec, How Mac one will
   appeared in security and privacy setting? Is it turned on like below picture?
   [image: security and privacy setting]

May be I will have to use packet capture? I'm not familiar with the browsing packet. So if you could advice me, That would be helpful for me.

Comment: I added pictures of the screenshot again according to @G Koe's answer. and updated about firewall setting.

Answer (score 1):

Check the error you're receiving:

If you can load the webpage using another browser, but not Google Chrome, check the exact error you're getting by clicking the More information on this error link on the page.

If you're getting "Error 124 (net__ERR_WINSOCK_UNEXPECTED_WRITTEN_BYTES)," see the Error 124 troubleshooting article.

For the following errors, try the solutions below:

- Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)
- Error 2 (net::ERR_FAILED): Unknown error
- Error 104 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED)
- Error 105 (net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED)
- Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): Unknown error
- Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

Clear your cookies:

Cookies are files created by websites you've visited to store browsing information, such as your preferences for the website or profile information. A corrupted cookie file may be causing this error to show up. Follow these steps to clear your cookies:

Click the Chrome menu Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.

1. Select Settings
2. Click Show advanced settings.
3. In the "Privacy" section, click Content settings
4. In the "Cookies" section, click the All cookies and site data.
5. Click Remove all. Click X to close
   the dialog.

Make sure Google Chrome is allowed in your antivirus and firewall settings:

- Each program works differently, so check your software's help resources for further instructions.

Are you using a proxy?  Please try disabling it in system preferences --> Networking --> Active internet connection (usually marked as green circle).

Then click on "Advanced..." button.
 - Select Proxies tab.

Uncheck "Web Proxy" and "Secure web proxy"

Comment: @G Koe, thank you for the information. I have checked them and it seems be there is not affected setting.

Comment: does this issue persist after a reboot?

Comment: @G Koe, Yes I rebooted my mac and had a problem.

Comment: Navigate to chrome://net-internals/#dns and press the "Clear host cache" button.  AND   Navigate to chrome://net-internals/#dns and press the "Clear host cache" button.

Comment: See More details here, as I'm fairly sure it is a CHROME DNS problem: http://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome

Comment: @G Koe, I tried but It did not work for me thank you for your help. I will rebuilt in a couple of days due to other purpose. Then I will know the problem this is on purpose by someone or not.