# No Internet in Chrome but MS Edge (Chromium) works fine, how is it possible?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

For some weird reason, chrome stops working in between. If restart the system it works again.

```
"No internet
Try:
 Checking the network cables, modem, and router
 Reconnecting to Wi-Fi 
 Running Windows Network Diagnostics 
 DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET"
```

Am asking this question, using the same internet via MS Edge (Chromium). I tried other Microsoft products like IE, MS Edge, all working fine except chrome.

AFAIK, MS Edge (chromium) and Chrome both are based on chromium, but why it behaves different in different systems?

Case #1: Disabled all extensions, Same result

Case #2: Updated to latest build, Same result

Case #3: Uninstalled and Installed again, same result

Case #4: Stopped Sync, Deleted all info, same result

Case #5: Updating regedit values didn't help, same result

Comment: Are you using a proxy or something?

Comment: Are you using some kind of firewall? If so, check its rules. Or anti-virus (e.g. _Bitdefender_). Most likely Chrome was added to the black list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome is unable to connect to the Internet](https://superuser.com/questions/804438/chrome-is-unable-to-connect-to-the-internet)

Comment: Try running `netsh winsock reset`.

Comment: Am using proxy, firewall and antivirus. I'll try the workaround in another answer and will update.

Comment: @Dineshkumar, any update to this? Have the same issue, the listed answers did not fix.. Any update from when you had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your computer dns issue . Try changing the default dns to Google public dns

> 8.8.8.8

Also you may fix this DNS error by using below commands:

```
ipconfig /release

ipconfig /renew

ipconfig /flushdns

netsh int ip set dns

netsh winsock reset
```

Comment: Not a DNS issue for me as DNS resolves immediately and even when trying to visit sites by IP, ERR_TIMED_OUT on chrome, but OK in Edge..

Answer (score 0):

Almost as @Asad answered, I found this here that seems to work (it was not the case for me but this is what I found in several forums/tutos):

```
netsh winsock reset

Do not restart

netsh int ip reset

Restart
```

In case you have a "Resetting , failed." "Access is denied." error in `netsh int ip reset`, follow this to fix it: https://davidvielmetter.com/tricks/netsh-int-ip-reset-says-access-denied/

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this issue by turning off the WiFi network masking the antivirus software does.

Aura antivirus has a feature to mask the location as a layer of protection.  It can be turned on and off.

I noticed a consistent correlation between chrome not finding the network when masking was on and no issues in Chrome if the masking is turned off

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Which virus scanner was this and where is that setting?

Answer (score 0):

i trouble shot everything suggested with no luck. Then I ran the McAfee software removal tool and internet works again on chrome. The tool I used was here: https://www.mcafee.com/support/?articleId=TS101331&page=shell&shell=article-view

Comment: As in, you had to remove McAfee from your computer? Note that OP didn't mention McAfee in their set or issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and finally I was able to solve it by going to Chrome settings, under the "Privacy and Security" option, then "Security", then "Use Secure DNS" and finally checking the "With your current service provider" option. That solved the problem instantly. Cheers!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).