# Chrome ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED after nameserver change

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, dns, apache-http-server, browser-cache

I've created my first ubuntu 14.04 server on digital ocean and tried to point my domain to it. Ive configured everything with help of the following [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) to set up my apache virtual host. When i go to the domain now ( a few hours after changing the nameserver for the domain) I get the following error when i go to the domainname in chrome :

```
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

However when I open it with another browser I get the testpage like in the tutorial. I flusheddns on windows and I cleared host cache in chrome from chrome://net-internals/#dns i've also cleared cache as suggested by the second answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome), and did multiple reboots.

What else can I try?

Comment: change your dns service to one that can route the domain, our other browsers work, likely because of a local cache.

Comment: @Ramhound the other browsers show the newfile which is completely different from the one that was on the original server. so it pointing definetly to the right one.

Comment: When i broswe on my mobile phone with a chrome browser the website works fine.

Comment: Are you using a proxy? Have you tried recently? Have you tried changing your DNS server?

Comment: @Ramhound nope im using no proxy, changing dns on the router didnt work. If i open another browser on the same pc it works fine, only chrome is not working.

Comment: nslookup display the correct information also this a secure http connection?

Comment: @Ramhound nslookup shos the right info, its not a https connection.

Comment: Disable DNS prefetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After completely removing chrome it still didnt work. The last option was uninstalling chrome and removing all chrome files /cache etc now the page loads correctly.