# chrome dns issue on ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, google-chrome, dns

I've got a local test server running on a virtual machine. It's running on a different computer from which I am working.
I browsed with google chrome to http://test/ and I received a dns error from my provider. Then I realized I didn't add the address in my /etc/hosts, so I did. I can now ping test and I get a reply from 192.168.0.5.
I can also browse to http://192.168.0.5 and receive the expected html.
However, if I browse to the first link, I get the ISP reply again.
If I add main.php, I do get to see the expected page.

I cleared all history and tried again, still I get the ISP reply.

How can I resolve this issue so I can browse to http://test/ and get the reply from my virtual machine?

Thanks in advance.

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 x64, have google-chrome x64 installed and everything is updated with the latest updates today.

Comment: Probably a repeat of http://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome

Comment: BTW, many ISPs will, instead of returning an error on a bad DNS lookup on their DNS servers, instead will answer with an IP taking you to a 'help' page, which often, of course, has advertising.   Problems like this are why that sort of redirect is bad IMHO.

Comment: Thank you so much. Would've put the link to the other question as best answer, but I can't do that with comments.

Comment: And sorry for the "duplicate" :) My bad... didn't find it before I posted the question.