# Does clearing/flushing the DNS cache in Google Chrome delete the history, etc.?

Tags: google-chrome, dns, ssl, cache

I had a couple of questions:

1. If I follow the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome), then will it also delete the history, auto-fill details, passwords, etc. from Google Chrome? (I just wanna double check before I proceed).
2. Can I do that only for one website?  I just updated my portfolio website with a SSL certificate.  So, ideally, I just want to update the DNS records in Chrome associated with *my* portfolio website.  Is there any way I can do this *only to my website*?  As I believe, step 1 above will do it for all the websites.

Thanks.

**Edit**:  I think I got it: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/cache.  Could someone please confirm, though?  Will this help my website open with 'https' instead of 'http' (the nameservers have got updated successfully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not clear anything other than your DNS cache, hence everything else will be where it was (passwords, auto-fill, etc).

The purpose of DNS is to resolve hostnames (such as google.com) and convert it to its IP address (172.217.12.46 in my case).

Your cache will simply repopulate itself once you revisit a website. If you didn't change your DNS server yourself, you are likely running DNS lookups through your ISP; but there are public DNS servers as well (such as google's @ 8.8.8.8).

If stale data is still with the DNS server, clearing your cache will not provide you any benefit. For example, your IP may have changed from 1.1.1.1 to 2.2.2.2, but if a DNS server contains outdated records then it may still point to the 1.1.1.1.

You can also redirect local traffic by modifying your [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)).

Comment: So I added a SSL certificate to my website.  It wasn't there before.  When I visit it from my MacBook, it still doesn't show 'https' (although visiting it from some other computer shows 'https').  **What should I do so that I can see 'https' in _my MacBook_ as well?**  Whatever I should do, I wish to do it _only to this particular website_ without touching the data of other websites in any way.  I got confused because of your answer.. could you please elaborate wrt my question in bold?

Comment: @Ganpat You probably want to redirect your users to the https site. But your original question had nothing to do with web hosting and I am not overly familiar with that topic unfortunately.